# Fatal error: Call to a member function getImage() on a non-object in ...Adapter/Product.php on line 812

Tags: import, magento-1.9

I am getting below error, when i'm try to import products from CSV file.

I have search for this error on SO and google but no luck,

Please guide me if any one have idea.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getImage() on a non-object in /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php on line <b>812</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Image for imported product in /media/import folder.

Comment: Yes @Swati, it there in /media/import folder, even i changed folder permission to 777